# Connect to MySQL database from ASP.Net MVC

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

im quit new to the ASP.Net MVC World. But i can't find any examples of, how to connect to an MySQL Database server from an ASP.Net MVC website. Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Description

At first you need to download the`MySQLConnector`. Then you can use the Entity Framework or the SqlCommand to connect to your database.

#### More Information

- [MySQL Connector for .NET](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net)
- [MySQL Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/articles/tutorial_ef.html)